# difference between std::randomize and class based randomize

Tags: system-verilog, verification, uvm

What is the difference between option A and Option B

### Option A:

```
sucess = std::randomize(type_l) with { 
   type_l inside { A ,B ,C};
   type_l dist { A := 2 ,B := 5 ,C := 4 }; 
};

if(  sucess == 0 ) begin
   `uvm_fatal("TEST_CFG", "type_l randomization failed")
end
```

### Option B:

```
class gen_type;

   enum_type type_l;

   constraint type_c{ 
      type_l inside { A ,B ,C};
      type_l dist { A := 2 ,B := 5 ,C := 4 }; 
   };       
endclass
```

Comment: do distribution is same in the both the case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here **Option A** is an example of inline constraints, in which one can randomize a local variable of a class or module or program block without declaring it as a `rand` or `randc`.

While **option B** is an example of a randomization of variables of the object. In this construct, you must declare a variable, which u want to randomize as a `rand` or `randc` (Here, you haven't declared the enum variable as `rand` or `randc`, so it'll give an error).

Please refer following link for more details. http://forums.accellera.org/topic/1235-stdrandomize-vs-randomize-vs-thisrandomize-and-scope/

Answer (score 0):

The basic difference is that `std::randomize` is a function not a class method and `class::randomize` is a class method. The `randomize` function can be used on any variable and any constraints must be inline constraints.

The `randomize` class method allows you to provide and control constraints for all instances of the class. It will always use the constraints specified in the class plus any optional inline constraints you provide. The `randomize` method also calls the `pre_randomize` method before doing the randomization and calls `post_randomize` after.

So:

Option A:

```
enum_type type_1;
std::randomize(type_1); // No constraints
```

Option B:

```
gen_type a;
a.randomize(); // Use constraints specified in class. Call pre/post_randomize
```

Answer (score -2):

**Option A**

- Not actually a randomization, but a method call with inline
  constraint.
- You can not modify that constraint, you don't have any
  control over it.

**Option B**

- Actually a randomization. You need to add **rand** or **randc** with
  type1 declaration, to get it randomized.
- You have complete control over randomization.
- You can turn on/off the constraint through constraint_mode method.
- You can turn on/off randomization of type1 through rand_mode method.